# geth js commands to handle my Wallet contract

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, javascript

I have created a Wallet contract using the Mist. Now I am trying to handle it using geth console javascript commands. By handling I mean sending ether to an account. Can someone help me with the js commands to do that? I have come this far:

```
abiDef = *interface from Mist*  
Wallet = eth.contract(abiDef);  
myWallet = Wallet.at(*address from Mist*);
```

So how do I send ether to an account using `myWallet`?

I found it :) :
https://github.com/ethereum/mist/wiki/Wallet-Contract